# how to detect that a particular app is not installed via my link or not

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing an app loosely based on mobile money and other apps so how can i detect that any app is installed via my link not from play store

Comment: You can add code while user download from your link  to count how many users downloaded app via your link..!!

Comment: Do you know that you can add referrer parameter to the link used to reach your app's Google Play Store page.

Comment: If you want a detailed explaination for referrals in Android, I can put up one.

Comment: yes i would like to have your code thanks in advance @crashOveride

Comment: Try Campaign in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to track download source would be using playstore with referral parameter added and using broadcast receivers within app to understand the source.

The playstore link should end looking somewhat like 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hellochatty&referrer=tracking_id%3D123456789

Configuring your app
The Android Manifest

First you need to register the broadcast consumer in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
 <receiver
 android:name=".receivers.InstallReceiver"
 android:exported="true" >
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
 </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Here we are configuring our app to listen to the intent INSTALL_REFERRER and receive the broadcast event by InstallReceiver.

InstallReceiver

```
public class InstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String rawReferrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
        if (rawReferrer != null) {
            trackReferrerAttributes(rawReferrer, context);
        }
    }

    private void trackReferrerAttributes(String rawReferrer, Context context) {
        String referrer = "";

        try {
            referrer = URLDecoder.decode(rawReferrer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return;
        }

        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(referrer)) {
            return;
        }

        Uri uri = Uri.parse('?' + referrer); // appends ? for Uri to pickup query string

        String memberCode;
        try {
            referringMember = uri.getQueryParameter("mcode");
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            return;
        }

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(
            BuildConfig.PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(memberCode)) {
            editor.putString(Constants.REFERRER_CODE, memberCode);
        }

        String referralMedium = uri.getQueryParameter("tc");
        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(referralMedium)) {
            editor.putString("referral_medium", referralMedium);
        }

        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

[Code reference](https://technology.jana.com/2014/11/11/tracking-referrers-for-your-android-app/)

You can also check and download sample code from [this git repo](https://github.com/agirardello/Android-Samples/tree/master/Custom%20Referrer%20Receiver)

Comment: thanks for your contribution but it's not working .. when an app installs Broadcast Receiver doesn't catch the referral code . Is there any more work to do to receive it?

Comment: did you test it this way:           am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.example.android.custom.referrer.receiver/.ReferrerReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_source=YourAppName&utm_medium=YourMedium&utm_campaign=YourCampaign&utm_content=YourSampleContent"

Comment: it gives Broadcast Completed : result = 0
it's not working is there any other thing left which i hadn't included?

Comment: I guess it is working. Put a debug log in there. before Uri uri = Uri.parse('?' + referrer); line after if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(referrer)) {
            return;
        }

Comment: it gives the data when you download the same app with your package name i want to implement if a user download an app like amazon then how would i determine he has downloaded the app from my app not from google play .. thanks

Comment: via this program you can check if your app is installed via a particular link. You wont able to determine if amazon was downloaded through your link. Amazon will have to convey that information.